# Put a view at the end of UIScrollview - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

My aim is to set a UIView at the end (right bottom) of a UIScrollView. I saw solution using UIContentSize but I don't want to use this property because it is not adapted : The UIView width isn't equal to the UIScrollview contentSize.

The UIView is a subview of the UIScrollView and I only need to scroll horizontally. I think I must use constraints in order to stick my UIView at the end of the UIscrollview (that means the UIView Right side is the same that the UIScrollView right side, both have the same height)

What I did is :

```
let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.myView , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.myScrollView , attribute:  NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

self.myScrollView.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)

let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.myScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

self.myScrollView.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)
```

I'm a bit confused and stuck about how to set this constraints, I'm probably wrong because my view doesn't display anymore. Do I need to define all the constraint or only the one for the right and one for the top ? Any advice ? Thanks

EDIT : 
The solution I want could be represented like this : [image]

Comment: When you say "at the end" of the UIScrollView, do you mean it appears when scrolling to the bottom, or it stays on screen floating over the scrollView? I'm assuming the former. So `myView` should be a subview of `myScrollView`. Also, your current vertical constraint is pegged to the top, not the bottom.

Comment: Hi @Tim, of course the UIView is a subview of the UIScrollview ; What I want is that when the user launch the app, it would display the uiview at the end of the scrollview which means to me that the user can scroll to the left direction but not to the right (It doesn't matter how much he/she can scroll to the left)

Comment: Got it, didn't realize you were scrolling horizontally. What else is in your `scrollView`? You said it's not showing up, my guess is it's covered up. Whatever view is the rest of the scrollView content, needs to be constrained to the left edge of `myView`.

Comment: Thanks for your replies @Tim, this is the only view contained in my UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

`UIScrollView` takes it's content size from it's subviews, so it will only be as large as what it contains. We can't set it's size independently. Everything should be in a subview.

Decide on the size of `myScrollView` you want:

```
let myViewWidth = myView.frame.width
let myViewHeight = myView.frame.height
let screenWidth = myScrollView.frame.width
let scrollContentWidth = myViewWidth + screenWidth
```

Create a subview, let's call it `widthView`

```
let widthView = UIView(frame: CGFloat(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollContentWidth, height: myViewHeight))
myScrollView.addSubview(widthView)

let leadingEdgeConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: widthView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: myScrollView, attribute:  NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    myScrollView.addConstraint(leadingEdgeConstraint)

let trailingEdgeConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: widthView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: myScrollView, attribute:  NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    myScrollView.addConstraint(trailingEdgeConstraint)

let widthContainerConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: widthView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: scrollContentWidth)
    myScrollView.addConstraint(widthContainerConstraint)
```

Now add your myView to that view:

```
widthView.addSubview(myView)
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: widthView , attribute:  NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    widthView.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)

let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: myViewHeight)
    widthView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)

let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: myViewWidth)
    widthView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
```

Comment: And the solution it appears to me is first to add the subview to the UIScrollView, then set the constraints (Bottom, Left) and afterwards change the content size of the UIScrollview. Is it correct?

Comment: I suppose that might work. I don't understand any logical reason why you would want to allow scrolling to the left without there being any content there. The purpose of a scrollview is to display content.

Comment: I draw this quickly to show you the problem (also update in my question). The indicator on the top right corner indicates the values of the bar Chart. That's why I want my View (which contain the chart) to be stuck on the right side. The green square represents the UIScrollView, the blue one the view. http://hpics.li/d459ecc

Comment: Thank you @Tim, the contentSize is good but the UIView right side isn't stuck to the end of the UIScrollView..

Comment: If you use the code I suggested, go back to just the Top and Right constraints, delete the others.

Comment: Mhh Im trying to find the good constraints to write with your junk of code concerningthe contentSize but this constraints NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.myView , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.myScrollView , attribute:  NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0) with         self.myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false makes disapear the view :/

Comment: Check the updated answer. The best solution is to put `myView` in an intermediate view. Also, the reason it's disappearing is the lack of width and height constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to informations provided by @Tim I finally managed this without using another Subview :

Solution :

```
   // Create a view

    myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: self.myScrollView.frame.height))
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.myScrollView.addSubview(myView)


    //  constraints

    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


    let trailingSpaceConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.myScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: myView, attribute:  NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    myScrollView.addConstraint(trailingSpaceConstraint)

    let screenWidth = self.view.frame.width
    let leadingSpaceConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.myScrollView, attribute:  NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: screenWidth - 15)
    myScrollView.addConstraint(leadingSpaceConstraint)



    let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute:  NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 100)
    myScrollView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)

    let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.myScrollView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.myView, attribute:  NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0) 
    myScrollView.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)


    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.myScrollView, attribute:  NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    myScrollView.addConstraint(topConstraint)

    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.myView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.myScrollView, attribute:  NSLayoutAttribute.Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    myScrollView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
```